# Python packaging distribute post-install step

Tags: python, packaging, setuptools, distutils, distribute

I am packaging a project that uses nltk. When you install nltk with pip, you get core functionalitiy, but not all the modules that come with it. To get those modules, you call nltk's download method.

I tried the following, but it doesn't work, saying `ImportError: No module named nltk`. I assume this is happening because import nltk occurs before nltk is installed by the call to `setup(...)`.

Is there a clean way of having a post-install step with [distribute](http://pythonhosted.org/distribute/) that executes one of the following?

```
$ python -m nltk.downloader punkt
>>> import nltk; nltk.download('punkt')
```

Here's my failed attempt at `setup.py`:

```
class my_install(install):
    def run(self):
        install.run(self)
        import nltk
        nltk.download('punkt')

setup(
    ...
    install_requires = [..., 'nltk==2.0.4'],
    cmdclass={'install': my_install},
)
```

Answer (score 0):

pip does not handle dependencies, so you'll need to write a README file and explain your users what they need to install, or a script that runs pip install on all the things you need.

This second way would be the way to go I think, along with the README file that explains what is going on.

As a debian maintainer I can tell you that doing an installation command that downloads stuff around is considered not acceptable there, it would have to be packaged listing the dependencies to other packages and then installing yours if the dependencies are met, and I think it is a sane way to proceed in general. http://wiki.debian.org/UpstreamGuide#No_Downloads

Answer (score 0):

I used command line installation method and was successful.
like this...

```
import subprocess

class my_install(install):
    def run(self):
        install.run(self)
        cmd = ["python", "-m", "nltk.downloader", "punkt"]
        with subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE) as proc:
            print(proc.stdout.read())
```